# using query to show data in jsf

Tags: jsf, jdbc

i have a question here
say i have a table like this

no  product id  product name  price  description        stock category

1    PR001      Peugeot 206  20000   a hatchback sedan   10     sedan

2    xxxxx      xxxxxxxxxxx  xxxxx   xxxxxxxxxxxx        xxx    van

i want to show the table in my page based on category, so when i ask

```
select PRODUCT_ID, PRODUCT_NAME, PRICE, DESCRIPTIONK, STOCK from APP.PRODUK where CATEGORY = 'sedan'
```

it will show like this

no  product id  product name  price  description        stock category

1    PR001      Peugeot 206  20000   a hatchback sedan   10     sedan

My question is, how to do that using jsf ? i am using JDBC here

Answer (score 0):

In order to show it in JSF

1. create the class - car. Add getters and setters to the class.

> public class Car{
>
> ```
>     Integer id;
>     Integer productId,
>     String productName,
>     Double price;
>     String description,
>     Integer stock;
>     String category;
> }
> ```

1. Create your JSF Bean

> ```
>  @ManagedBean
>  public class DataBean{
>           @PostConstruct  
>           public init(){
>           cars = ...write your code to retrieve the cars   
>            }  
>            private List<Car> cars;
>
>        public getCars(){
>           return cars;  
>         }
>       }
> ```

1. Create a xhtml page with:

> ```
>   <h:dataTable value="#{dataBean.cars}" var="car">
>       <h:column>
>       <f:facet name="header" >
>                <h:outputText value="No."/>
>            </f:facet>    
>       <h:outputText value="#{car.id}"/>
>        </h:column>
>         <h:column>
>       <f:facet name="header" >
>                <h:outputText value="Product Id"/>
>            </f:facet>    
>       <h:outputText value="#{car.productId}"/>
>        </h:column>
>
>     </h:dataTable>
> ```

I wrote only 2 columns. But copy and change for the rest.

For more information, refer to the search engines to find out about `<h:dataTable>`